# Is it possible to destroy a session variable set by ASP.NET (VB.NET) with Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, vb.net, session

As the title states, I have a session variable that is set during a login script with asp.net and vb.net code-behind. Can I call a javascript function when a link is clicked that will destroy that session variable?

If it is possible, can I use jQuery to make that process easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `$.post("logout.aspx");` in your Javascript, and create the file logout.aspx that destroys the session.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side code (VB.NET in your case) is the only thing that can access the session and its variables. Your best bet is to create a WebService/WebMethod and use jQuery to call it.

This article should help you get started: [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Answer (score 1):

Not explicitly - session variables live on the server, while Javascript operates in the client.

The best you can do is use JS to send a request to the server (possibly via Ajax), that will cause the server to delete the sesion variable.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the ASP.NET Session cookie

```
document.cookie = 'ASP.NET_SessionId=xxx';
```

Comment: I think he's just looking to delete a specific session variable, not abandon the whole session.